# Rails show latest value after grouping

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

If I have this database table **servers**:

**date, server_id, server_name, server_status**

I have set in my controller:

```
@servers = Server.all.group(:server_id)
```

And assuming in my view I have a table like:

```
<% @servers.each do |server| %>

<td><%= server.server_name %></td>

<td><%= server.server_status %></td>
```

How do I show the server status at the most recent date recorded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@servers = Server.order(created_at: :desc).group(:server_id)
```

Comment: But supposing I want the table in view showing results ordered by server_name that wouldn't work isn't it?

Comment: @Catmal you can order by more, than one column: `Server.order('server_name DESC, created_at DESC')`

Comment: Ok sorry I was meaning let say I allow sorting in view with ransack for instance. Is it possible that would mess  up the result?

Comment: ransack will do it's job and it has nothing to do with the initial ordering you are presenting in your view.

Comment: If I can ask and if the solution is easy. Otherwise maybe I make a new question. If I want to show let say last recorded and first recorded status. How would I put the 2 separate ordering asc and desc?

Comment: @Catmal if you think of it - you can't have both directions of ordering at the same time for the same column. You could have something like ordering ascending by one column and descending by another

Comment: Yes that's why. I was actually expecting a solution by using something like a a class method or a scope. But ok this is the easiest way to achieve what I asked. I will think better about it and make a new question if i need.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you're adding a new record with a timestamp and status every time you update a server's status? If that's correct, you'll need to `GROUP BY server_id` and `ORDER BY date DESC`.

That can be expressed in SQL as

```
SELECT * FROM servers GROUP BY server_id ORDER BY date DESC;
```

or in Rails' ActiveRecord as

```
Server.all.group(:server_id).order(:created_at => :desc)
```

(As a side-note, I'd recommend calling this model something like `ServerStatus` rather than just `Server` - it's representing the status, not the server itself.)