# Rails group and show oldest and latest value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401324/rails-show-latest-value-after-grouping) I asked previously.

database table **servers**:

> date, server_id, server_name, server_status

By using this in my controller:

```
@servers = Server.order(date: :desc).group(:server_id)
```

I can show latest server status in my view with:

```
<td><%= server.server_status %></td>
```

How can I show on same table in view the first status too? Basically by ordering by date in the opposite way.

I know it doesn't really make sense in this context but I used the example in the first question to make it clearer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you are asking

```
#controller
servers_acending = Server.order(date: :asc).group_by {|i| i.server_id}
@first_last_pairs = servers_acending.map {|k, v| [v.first, v.last]}

#your view 
<%@first_last_pairs.each do |pair|%>
  <td><%= pair.first.server_name %></td>
  <td><%= pair.first.server_status %></td>
  <td><%= pair.last.server_name %></td>
  <td><%= pair.last.server_status %></td>
<%end%>
```

This was you can show the first one in the table

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This work to show first value. But what do I put in my view to show both first and last in separate columns?

Comment: Updated, there is no reason to use a loop just place the `td` elements

Comment: I think shows same value in all rows. Which doesn't work as there are different servers. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I mean it shows first and last for the whole table not only for records regardin a particular server. So all rows, containing a different server (as it's grouped by server), show the same status (first or last among all values in the table)

Comment: Ok are you trying to show more than 2 values in this table? You said you are trying to show the first and the last value based on date. So what other values are you referring to?

Comment: I mean for each server are recorded different statuses at different dates. If I have 2 rows in database: 1/1/2016, Server A, online and 2/1/2016, Server A, offline. Then in my view I'd have Server A, online, offline.

Comment: So you want to show the first and last value based on date for each server?

Comment: Ok I updated let me know if that is what you are looking for

Comment: This returns undefined method `first' for #<Server:0x00

Comment: This returns no error but shows the same value for both start and end in all rows..

Comment: How many records do you have? can you post a print out of all the records for one server in your question?

Comment: Ok this solution seems to work except that in the view I am already looping `@servers` and I'm not sure how I should loop it with `@first_last_pairs`

Comment: There should only be one pair

Answer (score 0):

This will also work for you:

```
@servers_latest = Server.all.group(:server_id).order(:date => :desc)
@servers_oldest = Server.all.group(:server_id).order(:date => :asc)
```

Comment: How do I implement that in my view? I tried but I have problem to run the 2 loops. If you could show it would help..